# Multiple pricebooks on one opportunity

Tags: opportunity, pricebook, product

I've seen this question a few times, but there never seems to be a resolution. How can I make it possible to link multiple pricebooks to an opportunity? We're trying to implement something in our org where Pricebooks/Products would be the perfect solution, except for that one piece. Without being able to link multiple pricebooks to an opportunity, the solution is worthless. I can go into more detail if it's needed.

I'm okay with Apex and VF if that's the only solution, but could use some guidance on how to get started.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The opportunity's PriceBook2Id field is just that: a single field that holds a single value. Further, the system automatically rejects new line items that don't match the selected price book. So, OOTB, you can only use one price book. You will need to use an alternative solution in order to do what you're trying to do, or [vote this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpRfAAK) and maybe it'll get implemented eventually.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that post. Since it's 8 years old I'm not holding my breath on it happening any time soon. What would the alternative solution be?